# Whats wrong with this AppendChild Call?

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

i am trying to do this simple AppendChild, Call with no success:

```
//Create Video and Apply
function makeVid(src,wW,hH,Ref){
    var NewSrc= SrcCollect[Ref];
    var ambVid= document.createElement("VIDEO");
    ambVid.setAttribute("width",wW);
    ambVid.setAttribute("height",hH);
    ambVid.setAttribute("src",src);
    ambVid.setAttribute("controls","controls");
    ambVid.className="ambiVidElement";        
    ambVid.id="ambiVidElement"+Ref;
    var holder = document.getElementById("ambi_vid_wrapper"+Ref);
    holder.appendChild(ambVid);
}
```

It produces no errors, even if i use try{} to catch the error, there is none, but the element i created and want to append does not appear on the page...

Comment: Try setting its CSS property `display` to `block`. New elements might be created with `display: none`.

Comment: Does the browser you use support the tag at all?

Comment: It seems like you're doing everything right, but knowing how moody direct creation of DOM elements tends to be, try instead to create a simple container (`container = createElement("DIV")`), and insert the Video as innerHTML into it (container.innerHTML = "<video...>" before doing appendChild of the container. It seems like browsers in many cases insert DOM elements created directly just fine but don't run through their "special properties" like loading the script with `<script src=...>` or starting the plugin with `<embed>`...

Answer (score 0):

It's very odd there are no errors, have you checked your browser's JavaScript console? Walked through with [a debugger](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html)?

A few suggestions below (changed lines flagged with `*`):

```
//Create Video and Apply
function makeVid(src,wW,hH,Ref){
    var NewSrc= SrcCollect[Ref];
    var ambVid= document.createElement("video"); // * lower-case
    ambVid.style.width = wW + "px";              // * setting style properties
    ambVid.style.height = hH + "px";             // *
    ambVid.src = src;                            // * `src` is a reflected property on most elements with a `src` attribute
    ambVid.setAttribute("controls","controls");
    ambVid.className="ambiVidElement";        
    ambVid.id="ambiVidElement"+Ref;
    var holder = document.getElementById("ambi_vid_wrapper"+Ref);
    holder.appendChild(ambVid);
}
```

Aside from the above, I'd double-check that the `getElementById` call is returning what you expect it to return.

Making this a CW answer because it's really more just a series of debugging suggestions.

Comment: Thx for your suggestions but i think i found the issue, it is related to Safari 5 Extensions triggering the scripts from all frames and each page snippet, it works, but it gets restetted by another call i dont want to, so the apply works like expected but gets overridden by another call...

Comment: Found the issue, it remains to the behaviour of Safari 5 Extensions code injection, it worked but got ovrerridden by another call and was removed...